# Project in eclipse lost references to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

Yesterday, during closing of Eclipse when it was saving workspace error appeared that it could not save the changes. After starting Eclipse again half of my projects lost references to the repository.  [Here is an image with function's that are still available to me with Teams option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TeKu.jpg) . I tried to connect to SVN  again with apply patch but it was displaying error  "URL does not contain valid patch." but... the same path is used in jenkins for build process and it works there.

On stackoverflow I found information that someone had similar problem and reopening project helped... in my case doing so lead to having empty project afterwords. I also tried to look for teams->share project option but I could not find it. I wonder what was the reason for this problem in the first place and the main question is: how to set it all back so I could connect to the repository?

***EDIT***

Regarding to the question in the comments. I'm adding image of
 Project: Properties: Subversion
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5npq.png)

Comment: _Team > Share Project..._ will be shown after _Team > Disconnect_. Please show _Project > Properties: SVN_.

Comment: @howlger Thank You for the answer. I have added image for properties in my post. Image is for the project that lost references. In case of projects that are working properly all fields: Path, Url, Repository Roots etc. are filled with information's.

Comment: In the _SVN Repositories_ view are the associated repositories still there and can be browsed? If yes, you might try to disconnect and re-share the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end re-importing all projects from file system helped and every project was properly connected to the repository. It seems as eclipse error as in the system explorer, in the workspace folder I could using TortoiseSVN do all functions such as commit, switch etc. and it did not worked only in Eclipse. Problem is solved but still it would great to find out what was the cause for that to prevent similar issues in the future.